# React.js onClick event: TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs, event-handling, undefined, i18next, typeerror

Currently having tough times learning React and JavaScript.

I've got two components, **Navigation**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Nav from './houses/Nav.js';

// set data
var navbar = {};
navbar.brand = {linkTo: "#hero", text: "text"};
navbar.links = [
      {linkTo: "#", event:"es", spanClassName: "flag-icon flag-icon-es"},
      {linkTo: "#", event:"en", spanClassName: "flag-icon flag-icon-gb"},
      {linkTo: "#about", text: "about", spanClassName: "btnicon icon-user"},
      {linkTo: "#contacts", text: "contacts", spanClassName: "btnicon icon-envelope-open"}
  ];

class Navigation extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
    <header>         
      <Nav {...navbar} />        
    </header>
    )
  }
}

module.exports = Navigation;
```

and **Nav**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Nav extends React.Component {    

  render() {

    const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
      i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
    } 

      return(
        <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span className="sr-only" lang="lt">Toggle nav</span> 
                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <NavBrand linkTo={this.props.brand.linkTo} text={this.props.brand.text} />
            </div>
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <NavMenu links={this.props.links} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      );
    }
  };

  class NavBrand extends React.Component{
    render() {
      return (
        <a className="navbar-brand" alt="back to home" href={this.props.linkTo}>{this.props.text}
            <span className="brandicon"></span> 
            <span className="brandname"></span>   
        </a>
      ); 
    }
  };

  class NavMenu extends React.Component{
    render() {
      var links = this.props.links.map(function(link){       
          return (
            <NavLink linkTo={link.linkTo} text={link.text} active={link.active} event={link.event} spanClassName={link.spanClassName} />
          );

      });
      return (
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          {links}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  };

  class NavLink extends React.Component{
   render() {        

    if (this.props.event){
      return(
        <li><button onClick={() => changeLanguage(this.props.event)}>{this.props.event}<span className={(this.props.spanClassName)}></span></button></li>
      )
    }
    return(        
      <li className={(this.props.active ? "active" : "")}><a href={this.props.linkTo}>{this.props.text} <span className={(this.props.spanClassName)}></span></a></li>
    );
  }
};


  module.exports = Nav;
```

Currently I want to add a custom onClick event only to a certain     `<li>`elements with language attribute. It should render this:

The working onClick event inside other component's render() looks like this:
       `onClick={() => changeLanguage('lang_attribute')}`
So I should get the same result but through the navigation render

Pressing rendered button I get the error message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeLanguage' of undefined`

Need some  help with working sample

**UPDATE**
It seems that my question is related mostly to 18next. I was studying the i18n documents (cause additionally I must make a translation for a menu items) and made some tries, but as I understand the problem is with HOC and i18n functions. They are out of scope, because here are several classes.
So I getting two errors: t is not a function and i18n is undefined.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {translate} from 'react-i18next';


class Nav extends React.Component {

  render() {

      return(
        <nav className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span className="sr-only">Toggle</span> 
                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>              
              <NavBrand linkTo={this.props.brand.linkTo} text={this.props.brand.text} />
            </div>
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <NavMenu links={this.props.links} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      );
    }
  };

  class NavBrand extends React.Component{
    render() {

      return (
        <a className="navbar-brand" alt="back to home" href={this.props.linkTo}>{this.props.text}
            <span className="brandicon"></span> 
            <span className="brandname"></span>   
        </a>
      ); 
    }
  };

  class NavMenu extends React.Component{
    render() {

      const { t, i18n } = this.props;

      var links = this.props.links.map(function(link, index){         
          return (
            <PureNavLink  linkTo={link.linkTo} text={t(link.text)} active={link.active} event={link.event} spanClassName={link.spanClassName} />
            /*text={t(link.text)}*/  

          );

      });
      return (
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          {links}
        </ul>
      );
    }
  };

  class PureNavLink  extends React.Component{

    render() {        
      const { t, i18n } = this.props;
      const toggle = lng => i18n.changeLanguage(lng);       

      if (this.props.event){        

        return(  
          <div>               

          <button onClick={() => toggle(this.props.event)}>{t(this.props.event)}</button>          
          </div>        
        )
      }

      return(        
        <li className={(this.props.active ? "active" : "")}><a href={this.props.linkTo}>{this.props.text} <span className={(this.props.spanClassName)}></span></a></li>        
      );
    }
  };

  const NavLink = translate()(PureNavLink);
  module.exports = translate()(Nav);
```

Comment: Can you place your code in jsfiddle / codepen ? It will be easier for us to help you solving the issue

Comment: Here is not mine codePen with a bit different approach - React.createClass: https://codepen.io/zhaozhiming/pen/LNGyvR But the logic is the same

Comment: @Kuzma - You can't directly call parent's method in child component. You can use props to pass function from parent to child component. Place changeLanguage method above render() and remove const.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of Parker is correct

a) move changeLanguage like in the code above - but also `import i18n from '../i18n';` or where you defined your i18n instance.

```
import i18n from 'i18n';

// define the function outside of component scope
const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
  i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
};

// function is now available for use in any component in
// this module - just export it to use it in other modules
class Nav extends React.Component {

  render() {
    // your code and other components
  }
}
```

Or b) pass changeLanguage down via props.

```
// ...
<NavMenu links={this.props.links} changeLanguage={changeLanguage} />

// ...
<NavLink changeLanguage={changeLanguage} linkTo={link.linkTo} text={link.text} active={link.active} event={link.event} spanClassName={link.spanClassName} />
```

Or c) decorate your NavLink with the translate hoc

```
class PureNavLink extends React.Component{

    render() {        
      const { t, i18n } = this.props;
      const toggle = lng => i18n.changeLanguage(lng); 

      if (this.props.event){        

        return(  
          <div>               

          <button onClick={() => toggle(this.props.event)}>{t(this.props.event)}</button>
          </div>        
        )
      }

      return(        
        <li className={(this.props.active ? "active" : "")}><a href={this.props.linkTo}>{this.props.text} <span className={(this.props.spanClassName)}></span></a></li>        
      );
    }
  };

const NavLink = translate()(PureNavLink);
```

https://react.i18next.com/components/translate-hoc.html.

Or d) use the render prop I18n https://react.i18next.com/components/i18n-render-prop.html

Comment: Thank you Jamuhl for you help! Very weird situation, now in this module I'm getting annoying error - `t is not a function`. The `import i18n from './i18n';` is already done in *index.js*. In this, nav.js module, I've got `import {translate} from 'react-i18next';` and in the end I have `  const NavLink = translate()(PureNavLink);
  module.exports = translate()(Nav);` as you suggested. I've updated the last code sample, to show, how it looks like now

Comment: Sorry, didn't understood how to implement it.
In *Nav.js* component there are 4 classes: *Nav, NavBrand, NavMenu and PureNavLink(or NavLink)*.
All of them except *NavBrand* should use `t` function to make translations.
As I understood all classes should be wrapped inside HOC translate function, but it's impossible due to one possible `module.exports = translate()(Nav);`
Could you please provide an example?

Comment: you can do `const heyThisIsExtended = translate()(Nav);` no need to export  if you do not need to import it somewhere else - and if needing to export multiple classes use named exports -> honestly - without want to sound rude - you should learn a few basics of javascript programming...

Comment: Thank you for explanations!

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like you define your `changeLanguage` function inside of your `render()` method for the `Nav`. Therefore, `changeLanguage` is bound to the scope and context of `Nav`, so your `NavLink` component knows nothing about it. Try moving `changeLanguage` out of any component first, and see if it gets invoked, i.e.

```
// define the function outside of component scope
const changeLanguage = (lng) => {
  i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
};

// function is now available for use in any component in
// this module - just export it to use it in other modules
class Nav extends React.Component {

  render() {
    // your code and other components
  }
}
```

Methods and functions defined in React components are bound to the instance of that component. The only way to invoke that function or method elsewhere is to either 1) Define that function outside of any component, or 2) Pass a reference to the function or method as a `prop` to your child components. If doing number 2, be sure to bind the `this` context of your original component, otherwise you'll get errors like you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Actually moving the `changeLanguage` out of the render and out of the class throws *TypeError: undefined has no properties* error. Please have a look how it's working here: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KoCD3kvA-4QJNaHpkxi

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that `i18n` was coming from a 3rd party library - I thought it was a prop you were managing yourself. Is this where it comes from: https://react.i18next.com/? If so, it looks you need to wrap every component that uses the `i18n` prop with `translate` in order to pass it in. Or you could pass it down from a parent to a child. I'll work on a fiddle for ya later, gotta get back to my day job :(

Comment: Yes, it's react i18next lang switch. It seems that I had to describe it earlier. Thank you! Will wait for a fiddle :)

Comment: So here's [one option](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KvE4wGJpUJapbLtRN1M): In this instance, we are passing the changeLanguage method down to our child `NavButton` component. When we do that, we bind the `this` reference for our parent component (it is the owner of the `changeLanguage` method after all) as well as the argument we want to pass into the method (our `lng`) variable. Using this strategy, you could render as many buttons as you wanted for languages using an array. Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thank you very much Parker! I will test it today

Answer (score 1):

//file.js

```js
import { useTranslation, withTranslation, Trans } from 'react-i18next';

class myClass extends Component{
    //...
    componentDidMount() {
        this.changeLanguage('de'); // en | fr
    }
    changeLanguage = (lng) => {
        const { t , i18n} = this.props;
        i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
    };

    render(){
        //...
    }
}
export default withTranslation()(myClass) // <-- this should solve the issue
```

Comment: Please explain the solution and how it resolves the problem.
You may find this helpful [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).